# Lemmatization using Spacy gives wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, topic-modeling, lemmatization

I have a csv file with 70k german tweets and want to lemmatize the text, but it reduces every tweets to only one word and the output looks completely wrong. I did several steps of data cleaning before, but the data looked fine until this step. Does anybody have an idea, what could be the problem?

This is my code:

```
def lemmatize(text, nlp):
    #nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
    doc = nlp(text)
    
    lemmatized_text = []
    
    for token in doc:
        lemmatized_text.append(token.lemma_)
        return " ".join(lemmatized_text)
    
Tweet_df.cleaned_data=Tweet_df.cleaned_data.astype(str)

#Performing lemmatization on every row
Tweet_df.cleaned_data=Tweet_df.cleaned_data.apply(lambda x:lemmatize(x,nlp))

print(Tweet_df)
```

As there have been some cells without value after the pre-cleaning and I got an error, I converted everything into strings before executing the lemmatization.

Output:

```
print(Tweet_df)
       Unnamed: 0  ...         cleaned_data
0               0  ...              Tochter
1               1  ...                 None
2               2  ...                 rewe
3               3  ...                     
4               4  ...                genau
          ...  ...                  ...
69285       69285  ...  Krankheitensammlung
69286       69286  ...                 uber
69287       69287  ...                bevor
69288       69288  ...                     
69289       69289  ...                Armut

[69290 rows x 14 columns]
```

Before it looked like this:

```
print(Tweet_df)
       Unnamed: 0  ...                                       cleaned_data
0               0  ...  tochter      klasse lehrer fach ausgebildet ei...
1               1  ...                                               None
2               2  ...  rewe netten kassiererin erhalten quasi rest sc...
3               3  ...              tragbaren zustande pure existenzangst
4               4  ...             genau konnen brauchen hilfe taxtherich
          ...  ...                                                ...
69285       69285  ...  krankheitensammlung lebe langer hartziv blocki...
69286       69286  ...  uber     alt kindheit jugend gewalt erleben mu...
69287       69287  ...  bevor urteilst uber frage armut gelandet freiw...
69288       69288  ...      kind bekommen       eins verloren depressi...
69289       69289  ...  armut unten leben wei vorher bine      lebe re...

[69290 rows x 14 columns]
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: In order to get more tokens, line `return " ".join(lemmatized_text)` should be unindented one level, otherwise `lemmatized_text` only contains the the lemma of the 1st token (if any).

Comment: Thank you so so much! This was the fault and the lemmatization works now. I'm so happy!